# Form submission for single text box and multiple textboxes

Tags: php, html

I am wondering that why a form is not submitted for multiple textboxes if it has no submit button? Whereas a form with just only one textbox even without any submit button gets submitted. Why is this like so?

This form doesn't submit

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txtname" value="test" />
    <input type="text" name="txtage" value="25" />
</form>
```

But this form does submit

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txtname" value="test" />
</form>
```

But if we include submit button for multiple textboxes then the form gets submitted.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txtname" value="test" />
    <input type="text" name="txtage" value="25" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does "without submit button" meaning you press enter to submit? then it's normal behavior that it will submit only one text-box as code it is.

Comment: @LetsSeo If I have single textbox and no submit button in the form, the form submits by pressing enter key. But if I have 2 textboxes but no submit button, then form is not submitting by pressing enter key. But if I include a submit button, then form gets submitted by pressing enter key.